# Prove or disprove: If $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, $a > 0$, and $p$ is a prime such that $p^4 \mid a^3$, then $p^2 \mid a$.

Tags: number-theory

Prove or disprove: If $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, $a > 0$, and $p$ is a prime such that $p^4 \mid a^3$, then $p^2 \mid a$.

I looked at the answers to the duplicate questions and I'm still confused. I can't even think of any counterexamples. Any tips on where to start?

Comment: Hint. Make up a few examples. Then \tTry writing the prime factorization of $a$.

Answer (score 3):

Write $a=p^nb$, where $p$ does not divide $b$. Then you have, from $p^4\mid a^3$, that $4\le 3n$. Does this imply that $2\le n$?